# How to modify a file within a docker image?

Tags: docker, neo4j

I am running a neo4j image on a Fedora and I have to change the `neo4j.conf` configuration file located in `<NEO4J_HOME>/conf`. But I don't know where the `neo4j_home` is.

According to [this answer](https://community.neo4j.com/t/where-is-neo4j-home/6488/5) from the `...` dropdown there should be a Terminal option that allows me to find it. But I can't find this `...`

[image]

Here is what I have in `/etc/`:

```
bash-5.1$ gedit /etc/n
nanorc             ndctl/             netconfig          networks           nfs.conf           nfsmount.conf      nftables/          nsswitch.conf      nsswitch.conf.bak
```

I can run my container:

```
bash-5.1$ docker run \
   --detach \
   --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
   --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
   --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
   --volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
   neo4j
ccd3b8da2f838770c850017d131c9ed4d3825cdcf7a3aaebf825a611bd58a315
```

But I when I reach the file system I can't edit the file:

```
bash-5.1$ docker exec -t -i zoologie /bin/bash
root@15c0a418743c:/var/lib/neo4j# cd /conf/
root@15c0a418743c:/conf# nano neo4j.conf 
bash: nano: command not found
root@15c0a418743c:/conf# vim neo4j.conf 
bash: vim: command not found
root@15c0a418743c:/conf# apk install vim
bash: apk: command not found
```

And while it seems there is a conf file within the container it doesn't seem there is the same thing in the conf volume I mounted:

```
bash-5.1$ pwd
/home/ac/neo4j/conf
bash-5.1$ ls
bash-5.1$
```

Comment: Your container is not called `neo4j` since you don't provide a name when starting. You can access it via its id `ccd3b8da2f838770c850017d131c9ed4d3825cdcf7a3aaebf825a611bd58a315`

Answer (score 0):

When installed on Debian or RPM based distros, the conf folder path is `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf`

Source: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

---

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/configuration/ explains how to change the configuration when running Neo4j from a Docker image. In a nutshell:

> There are three ways to modify the configuration:
>
> - Set environment variables.
> - Mount a /conf volume.
> - Build a new image.
>
> Which one to choose depends on how much you need to customize the image.
>
> […]
>
> ### 2. Mounting the /conf volume
>
> To make arbitrary modifications to the Neo4j configuration, provide the container with a `/conf` volume.
>
> ```
> docker run \
>    --detach \
>    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
>    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
>    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
>    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf:/conf \
>    neo4j:4.4
> ```

Comment: Hmm, It seems I haven't got that. Is it because I am running neo4j from a Docker image?

Comment: @UsingFedora35 If you are using Docker, you have to look at the file inside of your container. If you want to change it, create your own Docker image or mount a volume.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the tip, I guess that in this volume I will have to provide the updated neo4j.conf file. The problem is that I don't know what the original consists of and I struggle to get into the file system of my container image (I've updated my question with my attempt to do so)